# RBAC issues using MassTransit with Azure service bus and MSI authentication

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

We are using MassTransit (v.5.5.5) with Azure Service Bus in a .net core v.2.2 application running in a container within Kubernetes. During the Bus setup we create a token using the managed service identity (MSI), like this...

```
var tokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateManagedServiceIdentityTokenProvider();
var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
{
    IServiceBusHost busHost = cfg.Host(new Uri(Settings.Host), h =>
    {
        h.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        h.TokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        h.TransportType = Settings.TransportType;
    });
    ...
}
```

Within Azure, the MSI is configured with all 3 Service Bus permissions (Owner, Sender and Receiver) - as decribed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-managed-service-identity#built-in-rbac-roles-for-azure-service-bus).

When the application starts authentication seems to happen successfully but when MassTransit begins to listen on the specific queues we create it fails with the following error:

```
MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Transport.ReceiveTransport Error: 0 :
ReceiveTransport Faulted: sb://hostname.servicebus.windows.net/some-custom-queue, 
Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.UnauthorizedException: Generic: Failed during RBAC check, 
please make sure service resource provider is registered on your tenant.
```

Points to note:

- The application *does* create the temporary bus queue, and there are no errors to do with accessing it.
- The application *does **not*** create our custom queues.
- If the MSI permissions are removed then no queues are created and the error is different: `Authorization failed for specified action: Manage,EntityWrite.`
- For what it's worth we are using the AmqpWebSockets transport type.

It seems weird that the temporary queue is created but not our application-specific ones.

So I guess my question is this... have I done anything wrong or is this something that is not yet available for MassTransit using Service Bus with MSI?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does something like this sample work with the same identity: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-msi-servicebus-dotnet? If yes, could be something to do with the protocol.

Comment: I have the same issue using the `TokenProvider.CreateAadTokenProvider` with ClientId and ClientSecret. No solution found, yet.

Answer (score 3):

We came across the same issue. We are using Mass Transit 6.* and Azure Service Bus. When switched to MSI we start see the same error:

```
Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.UnauthorizedException: Generic: Failed during RBAC check, please make sure service resource provider is registered on your tenant. TrackingId:2644d62a-83a9-444f-8aeb-b4bdee2fa84d_G30, SystemTracker:NoSystemTracker, Timestamp:2020-02-13T15:54:49
    at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management.ManagementClient.SendHttpRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management.ManagementClient.PutEntity(String path, String requestBody, Boolean isUpdate, String forwardTo, String fwdDeadLetterTo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management.ManagementClient.CreateTopicAsync(TopicDescription topicDescription, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Contexts.NamespaceManager.<>c__DisplayClass25_0`1.<<RunOperation>b__0>d.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.RunOperation(Func`1 operation, TimeSpan operationTimeout)
    at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.RunOperation(Func`1 operation, TimeSpan operationTimeout)
    at MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Contexts.NamespaceManager.RunOperation[T](Func`1 operation)
    at MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Contexts.ServiceBusNamespaceContext.CreateTopic(TopicDescription topicDescription)
    at MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Pipeline.ConfigureTopologyFilter`1.ConfigureTopology(NamespaceContext context)
    at MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Pipeline.ConfigureTopologyFilter`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<Send>b__0>d.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at GreenPipes.PipeExtensions.OneTimeSetup[T](PipeContext context, Func`2 setupMethod, PayloadFactory`1 payloadFactory)
    at MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Pipeline.ConfigureTopologyFilter`1.Send(NamespaceContext context, IPipe`1 next)
    at GreenPipes.Agents.AsyncPipeContextPipe`1.Send(TContext context)
    at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Pipeline.JoinContextFactory`3.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<<CreateJoinContext>g__Join|0>d.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Pipeline.ClientContextFactory.CreateSharedContext(Task`1 context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.GreenPipes.IPipeContextSource<TContext>.Send(IPipe`1 pipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Transport.ReceiveTransport.<Receiver>b__12_0()
    at MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.Pipeline.JoinContextFactory`3.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<<CreateJoinContext>g__Join|0>d.MoveNext()
```

Finally we found that ASB Sdk `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management.ManagementClient` doesn't allow to create topics with slashes in path when tokens from MSI used. This code below return the same error:

```
         try
            {
                var address = "sb://[name].servicebus.windows.net";
                var tokenProvider = new TokenProvider.CreateManagedIdentityTokenProvider();();
                var _managementClient = new ManagementClient(address.ToString(), tokenProvider);
                var topicDefinition = new TopicDescription("myNewTopic/22222");
                await _managementClient.CreateTopicAsync(topicDefinition);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e);

                throw;
            }
```

Since MT uses special naming convention to setup messaging topology, we get topic path with namespace of particular message type. If we have message `MassTransitTest.Message1` it will be converted to topic `MassTransitTest/Message1` (with slash). To fix this we setup our own `IEntityNameFormatter`

```
public class MyEntityNameFormatter : IEntityNameFormatter
{
    readonly IMessageNameFormatter _formatter;

    public MyEntityNameFormatter()
    {
        _formatter = new ServiceBusMessageNameFormatter();
    }
    public string FormatEntityName<T>()
    {
        var entityName = _formatter.GetMessageName(typeof(T)).ToString().Replace("/",".");
        return entityName;
    }
}
```

and then

```
 var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(configurator =>
            {
                ...
                configurator.MessageTopology.SetEntityNameFormatter(new MyEntityNameFormatter());
                ...
```

This fixed our issue. (We tried use ~ instead of . but got some validation errors, so decided use dots)

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to reproduce the same error using Azure Service Bus SDK code directly in a .NET Core (3.0) ASP.NET application hosted in an AppService with Managed Identity.

```
string serviceBusNamespace = "busnamespace_here";

string queueName = "with_service_name/test"; // NOT working with RBAC
// string queueName = "testrbac"; // Works with RBAC - no /

var msiTokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateManagedIdentityTokenProvider();
var qc = new QueueClient(new Uri($"sb://{serviceBusNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/").ToString(), queueName, msiTokenProvider);

var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"Test {DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()}"))
{
    ContentType = "application/text",
    Label = "Scientist",
    MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
};

try
{
    await qc.SendAsync(message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return View(ex.ToString());
}
```

I found out that the error seems to be caused by the presence of a / in the queue name. It's a character that is allowed in the Service Bus but it doesn't seems to works quite nicely with RBAC Service Bus feature.
The same code works well if you use a SAS Policy instead of Managed Identity/Client Secret.

Here is my test Service Bus in image (using Service Bus Explorer) :

[image: Service Bus Topology]

## Mass Transit

I know Mass Transit can use entity path with slash character in it. Does that means we can't use RBAC to access those entities ?

I wasn't able to find what is the root cause.